# Augmenting User type for passport.js

Tags: typescript, express, namespaces, passport.js

I am trying to use correct User typing with passport.js.

Passport defines the User interface as the empty interface in the Express namespace here:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/22f314360cf1f8c273e9985748519cb07984dc79/types/passport/index.d.ts#L20

So, out of the box of course, code like the following yields the error "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'User'":

```js
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    cb(null, user.id);
  });
});
```

This makes sense.

I managed to avoid the error by doing type merging: in a .d.ts file, I have:

```js
// express_augmentation.d.ts

declare namespace Express {
  interface User {
    id: string
  }
}
```

and this works fine.

But, what if instead of manually specifying that a user has an id (and maybe an email, and other properties), I wanted to use my User class, which has an id?

I was thinking of doing something along the lines of:

```
// express_augmentation.d.ts

declare namespace Express {
  import MyUser from '../models/user';
  interface User extends MyUser {}
}
```

but this does not seem to work. I'm a bit stumped. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the problem was that the import failed - though nor tsc nor VSCode highlighted the issue.

This works:

```js
declare namespace Express {
  type MyUser = import('../models/user').default;
  interface User extends MyUser {}
}
```

For some reason, `import MyUser from '../models/user';` does not behave like in regular app code, where the default export is imported. I must say I am not familiar with the `... = import(...).default` construct, I'll have to read about it.

In the end, the code can be compacted further into:

```js
declare namespace Express {
  type User =  import('../models/user').default;
}
```